# How to access content of div with particular class on first occurance?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the content of div with particular class on first occurance:
This is my html

```
<div class="rowChannel">
       pks
    </div>

    <div class="rowChannel">
       p
    </div>

    <div class="rowChannel">
       k
    </div>
```

and this is my php code.

```
$pattern23 = "#<div class=\"rowChannel\">(.*?)<hr/>#is";
preg_match_all($pattern23, $body, $d);
```

But I do not get the desired output 
which is `pks`.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery for this ?

Comment: I want to do this using php.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should replace `<hr/>` with `</div>`.

If you are only looking for the first occurance, you can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

For example:

```
$body = <<<SOURCE
<div class="rowChannel">
       pks
    </div>

    <div class="rowChannel">
       p
    </div>

    <div class="rowChannel">
       k
    </div>
SOURCE;

$pattern23 = "#<div class=\"rowChannel\">(.*?)</div>#is";
$result = preg_match($pattern23, $body, $d);

print_r($d);
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

       pks


    [1] => 
       pks

)
```